# Combo box is show item twice in VB.net in winform

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, combobox

I am adding an item in winform Combobox from the database.
It showing everything perfectly when i Autocomplete mode is None and Auto complete source is Also None

The problem that I am facing is when I keep Autocomplete mode in Suggest Append and Auto complete source is Listitem, **it start showing every listitem twice**.

[Combobox dropdown When autocomplete mode and auto complete source is None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgsX9.jpg)

[Combobox dropdown When Autocomplete mode in Suggest Append and Auto complete source is Listitem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htfwh.jpg)

Here The Code

```
 Private Sub Combo_Focus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combo.GotFocus
        Combo.Items.Clear()
        Combo.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim ds As DataSet
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        dt = New DataTable()
        ds = New DataSet()

        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "Master_List"    'Query inside the Access Database
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM (" + cmd.CommandText + ") WHERE Account = @ac AND Supplier = @supp"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ac", CType(Account_txt.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@supp", CType(Supplier_txt.Text, String)))

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While (reader.Read())
            Combo.Items.Add(reader("Item_Name").ToString())
        End While

        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: It's not really clear why you would re-fill a ComboBox in its `GotFocus` event (have you verified how many times that event handler is called?). Avoid that event in any case. BTW, you have two `CommandText`, a DataSet that you never use and `ExecuteReader()` after you have already filled a DataTable, which you don't use. I suggest to take a look at some of the gazillion existing posts on this subject.

Comment: Doing db queries in the Got focus is probably not going to give you the best user experience.  Could I suggest a better way is to load your base data into memory once, then do things like Linq queries or datatable filters against the base data for filtering down data criteria

Comment: Did you test the sql statement in Access? Did it return the items twice?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for respose. So i use combo.gotfocus because i want to filter the combobox item based on data in Account_txt.Text and Supplier_txt.Text. Is there any other way that I could implement this filter other than GotFocus method?

Comment: @Hursey I would be really helpful if you can suggest any better way. As I am very new to  coding, I could not find any other better way to do the same

Comment: @KyleWang Yes I checked the SQL Statement, It returning item only once

Comment: @CoderBabu Try to set a breakpoint in ‘GotFocus’ event to see if the event is called more than once.